# What am I missing in Vue to mount this app?

Tags: vuejs3

New to Vue.js here.
The simplest task is returning this message :

> Failed to mount app: mount target selector returned null

Here are my files :

index.html :

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.2"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Vue !</h1>
    <script src=app.js> </script>

    <div id="app">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js :

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
    template: '<h2> I am the template</h2>',
})
app.mount("#app")
```

I get the same error with this CDN :
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The `script` tag was wrongly located above `<div id='app'><\div>` instead of below :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.2"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Vue !</h1>
    

    <div id="app">
    </div>

    <script src=app.js> </script>

</body>
</html>
```